# invalid Syntax rm -rf temp (Cygwin)

Tags: python, cygwin

**Shell/OS:** Cygwin/Windows 7

**Source code:** [Source code](https://github.com/tmbdev/ocropy)

**Required package:** [Required package](http://www.tmbdev.net/en-default.pyrnn.gz)

---

**Installation:**

I downloaded the following [Source code](https://github.com/tmbdev/ocropy) on windows. I moved the requited package to models and I installed the package by using the following command: `python setup.py install`

---

**Test:**

by using `Cygwin` I wanted to test the package by typing: ./run-test:

```
#!/cygdrive/c/Python27/python

rm -rf temp
ocropus-nlbin tests/testpage.png -o temp
ocropus-gpageseg 'temp/????.bin.png'
ocropus-rpred -n 'temp/????/??????.bin.png'
ocropus-hocr 'temp/????.bin.png' -o temp.html
ocropus-visualize-results temp
ocropus-gtedit html temp/????/??????.bin.png -o temp-correction.html

echo "to see recognition results, type: firefox temp.html"
echo "to see correction page, type: firefox temp-correction.html"
echo "to see details on the recognition process, type: firefox temp/index.html"
```

---

**Error:**

```
File "./run-test", line 3
    rm -rf temp
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

- What caused this error?

Comment: rm -rf temp is not a valid python command. This looks like a bash file or something.

Comment: it is actually. But When i try to run it by using the following command `./run-test` i get the previous error

Comment: Its actually not a valid python command, its a shell command. Just change the shebang like holdenweb said, and it should work.

Comment: @Hoopdady yes you are right. I didn't know the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#!` line says this is a Python script. So why would a shell command be acceptable syntactically?

Try `#!/bin/sh/` instead.

Comment: I am using cygwin. is `#!/bin/sh` the correct path? what `#!/bin/sh/`is doing exactly? What is it calling?

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) for an explanation of the shebang line, which should probably be `#!/bin/sh`.